# submit button two function revert to original state

Tags: javascript, button, submit

I have used the following code (adapted from an answer available on this site). The program works but the output reverts to the original information(i.e."change me" and "change me please") after replacing them with the new information. I appreciate your help because I am just starting to learn JS.

```
<p id="dest">Change please</p>
<p id="dest1">Change too please</p>


<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return foo();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 function foo() {
   doo();
   goo();

   return true;
       }

function doo() {
    x = document.getElementById("QID37_Total");   
    document.getElementById("dest").innerHTML=x.value;
    return true;
    }

function goo() {
    y = document.getElementById("QR~QID37~1");   
    document.getElementById("dest1").innerHTML=y.value;
    return true;
    }


</script>
```

Comment: "QID37_Total", "QR~QID37~1" where is defined

Comment: what exactly you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `return true;` to `return false;`.  My guess is that your `submit` button is refreshing the page.